# how to make a string into list with input in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

hello i want to make variable i input with read(X) into list,
for example :

```
give_word(Word,Hiddenword):-
    first_and_last(Word,First,Last),
    length(Word,Le),
    MiddleLe is Le-2,
    middle(Hidden,MiddleLe),
    append([First],Hidden,Firsthalf),
    append(Firsthalf,[Last],Hiddenword).

kremala:-
    write('Give a word:'),nl,
    read(Word),nl,
    give_word(Word,Hidden),
    write(Hidden).
```

if for example the user gives the word "person" i want the variable in the fact give_word to be a list Word=[p,e,r,s,o,n].

Comment: Can't you just use `atom_chars/2`? `atom_chars(person, L)` => `L = [p,e,r,s,o,n]`.

Comment: I didnt even know the fact thank you